# В чем ошибка MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Что не правильно? У меня есть скрипт в котором ищется имя и фамилию в строках с activation=1 мне кажется что проблема в строчке $getName (9 строка) вот код:
http://pastebin.com/hJK3sJWf

```
<table>
<?
include('bd.php');
$searchq = $_GET['name'];

$myrow = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users ');

$nameArr = explode(" ", $searchq);//Разделяем входную строку на 2 по пробелу
$getName = mysql_query('
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE
        (firstname LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($searchq)).'%"
        AND activation=1)
        OR (
        lastname LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($searchq)).'%"
        AND activation=1)

        OR (
            firstname LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($nameArr[0])).'%"
            AND lastname LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($nameArr[1])).'%"
            AND activation=1)

        OR (
            lastname LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($nameArr[0])).'%"
            AND firstname LIKE "%'.mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($nameArr[1])).'%"
            AND activation=1)

');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getName)){
    echo "
    <tr align='left'>

                <div class='all_users'>
                    <td>
                    <a href='page.php?id=".$row['id']."'>
                        <img src='".$row['avatar']."' title='".$row['lastname']." ".$row['firstname']."'>
                    </a>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        ".$row['login']."<br>
                        ".$row['lastname']." ".$row['firstname']."<br>
                        ".$row['school'].", ".$row['school_form']."<br>
                        ".$row['date_of_birth']."<br>
                    </td>
                </div>

        </tr>";
}
echo "</table><br><br><font size='5'><b>Інші користувачі</b></font><br><hr width='100%' color='blue'>";
?>
```

Comment: В чем выражается "не работа" скрипта? Какое-то неправильное поведение, сообщения об ошибках?

Comment: @cheops изменил

Comment: смените учебник, чудовищный код, а mysql_* функции просто не работают в php7

Comment: 1 - покажите код из bd.php, чтобы можно было предложить вам исправленную версию вашего кода. Как уже было замечено - он крайне устаревший и выглядит ужасно. Его нужно актуализировать. 2 - по вашей ошибке: код верный, на первый взгляд. Не хватает данных. Покажите, какие входные данные в $_GET['name'] и что возвращает запрос. 3 - запрос к бд выглядит... "перенасыщенным". Зачем столько раз повторять одно и то же? напишите "activation=1" один раз, а дальше уточняйте остальное через OR. И зачем экранировать снова и снова одно и то же...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, я бы порекомендовал вам упростить код до подобного вида. Замечу, что он от этого не становится особенно лучше, как уже было замечено, mysql_*-функции являются крайне устаревшими и их давно не рекомендуется использовать. Вместо них стоит использовать mysqli_*-функции или, еще лучше, ООП-версию MySQLi.

```
<table>
<?
include('bd.php');
$searchq = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_GET['name']));

$myrow = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users ');

$nameArr = explode(" ", $searchq);//Разделяем входную строку на 2 по пробелу
$getName = mysql_query('
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE
        activation=1
        AND
        (
            firstname LIKE "%'.$searchq.'%"
            OR
            lastname LIKE "%'.$searchq.'%"
            OR
            (firstname LIKE "%'.$nameArr[0].'%" AND lastname LIKE "%'.$nameArr[1].'%")
            OR
            (lastname LIKE "%'.$nameArr[0].'%" AND firstname LIKE "%'.$nameArr[1].'%")
        )

');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getName)){
    echo "
    <tr align='left'>
        <div class='all_users'>
            <td>
            <a href='page.php?id=".$row['id']."'>
                <img src='".$row['avatar']."' title='".$row['lastname']." ".$row['firstname']."'>
            </a>
            </td>

            <td>
                ".$row['login']."<br>
                ".$row['lastname']." ".$row['firstname']."<br>
                ".$row['school'].", ".$row['school_form']."<br>
                ".$row['date_of_birth']."<br>
            </td>
        </div>
    </tr>";
}
echo "</table><br><br><font size='5'><b>Інші користувачі</b></font><br><hr width='100%' color='blue'>";
?>
```

Для конкретного решения вашей проблемы дополните вопрос данными

```
var_dump($_GET['name'], $getName, $row);
```

Comment: var_dump($_GET['name'], $getName, $row); а что это? Для чего это и куда это?? Можно поподробнее

Comment: Загуглите var_dump, ну что вы в самом деле... var_dump выводит информацию о указанных переменных. Добавьте эту строчку в код и мы увидим, что в каждой из этих переменных.